# ios - sqlite database not opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database using the sqlite framework - i've set up a couple of methods to get the file path and to then open the database but I'm getting an "unable to open database" error (as you can see i've logged out the result of sqlite3_open)

this is my header file:

```
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface ProgListViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    sqlite3 *db;
}

-(NSString *) filePath;
-(void)openDB;
```

this is my implementation file:

```
//file path to db
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSLog(@"pathtest");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];
}

//open the db
-(void)openDB {
    NSLog(@"opentest");
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) !=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Database failed to open");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to use `NSDocumentDirectory` rather than `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

Comment: i did indeed, thank you!